# Cleanup of tables before adding FK's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

### Tables

`Customer`: `ID` (PK), various fields.

`CustomerDeleted`: Almost exact copy of the `Customer` table. Customers do frequently get duplicated in the `Customer` table (the process of adding a new customer only checks using common fields such as name and location, so if the user adding him/her mispells a name or a location, there'll be two records for the same customer in the `Customer` table), and as soon as a duplication is spotted, the last entry added will be removed from the `Customer` table and inserted into the `CustomerDeleted` table with a column storing the current/valid Customer ID.

`Beneficiary`: ID (PK), various fields.

`CustomerBeneficiary`: `CustomerID`, `BeneficiaryID` (PK both). Link table between the `Customer` and `Beneficiary` tables. Each customer can have a certain number of beneficiaries.

### What I'd like to do

Set the `CustomerID` and `BeneficiaryID` in the `CustomerBeneficiary` table as FK's of their respective tables.

### The issue

There may be records in `CustomerBeneficiary` with beneficiaries linked to both a current `Customer` and a `CustomerDeleted`, so if you simply try adding the FK pointing to the `Customer` table it will give you the following error

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

### How to...?

I need the `CustomerBeneficiary` table updated so that all records containing `CustomerDeleted` customer ID's are instead pointing to the valid/current customer ID. It is possible that a deleted customer ID is linked to the same beneficiary ID than the current customer ID, so an `UPDATE` statement cannot be executed as there would be duplicate PK's in the `CustomerBeneficiary` table.

I think that there will have to be an `INSERT` (to add new rows so that the current customers are pointing out to any beneficiary their duplicate account was linked to), followed by a `DELETE` (to get rid of all the rows in the `CustomerBeneficiary` table whose `CustomerID` is part of a deleted customer).

Now, although I know what needs to happen my SQL knowledge is pretty limited and I have absolutely no idea whatsoever of how to do such complex query. I hope that I have explained the situation well enough someone can give a hand.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add relations where a deleted customer has a relation and current customer doesn't

```
INSERT INTO CustomerBeneficiary  
SELECT DISTINCT cd.currentCustomer, cb.BeneficiaryID 
FROM CustomerBeneficiary cb 
INNER JOIN CustomerDeleted cd
    ON cb.CustomerID = cd.CustomerID
WHERE cb.CustomerID in (SELECT CustomerID
                        FROM CustomerDeleted
                        WHERE currentCustomerID is not null)
    AND
      cd.currentCustomerID not in (SELECT CustomerID 
                                 FROM CustomerBeneficiary
                                 WHERE CustomerID = cd.currentCustomerID
                                 AND BeneficiaryID = cb.BeneficiaryID )
```

Delete all relations with customers whom aren't at Customers table

```
DELETE
    FROM CustomerBeneficiary 
    WHERE CustomerID not in (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers)
```

Now you can add your foreing keys